# How to auto-select menu entry / bybass grub menu in custom debian iso?

Tags: installation, debian, debian-buster

I would like to have a fully automated debian install iso. For that I started by creating a custom iso with a preseed integrated in the /isolinux/txt.cfg but I would like to bypass the menu of the grub to proceed directly to the installation (not having to manually select "Install" on the menu .

When I manually select Insall, the preseed file is well used.

I am still in the testing phase, I use the example on the debian site as a preseed file: https: //www.debian.org/releases/buster/example-preseed.txt

Here is my txt.cfg file:

```
label install
    menu label ^Install
    kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
    append vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg --- quiet
```

Thank you in advance for your reply

Comment: Resolv by this two files :
txt.cfg 
label install
        menu label ^install
        menu default
        kernel /install.amd/vmlinuz
        append vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/initrd.gz file=/cdrom/preseed.cfg --- quiet

Comment: solinux.cfg 
# D-I config version 2.0
# search path for the c32 support libraries (libcom32, libutil etc.)
path 
include menu.cfg
default install
prompt 0
timeout 0